# ¿ Cómo evitar que el total de productos en mi carrito de compras vuelva a 0 en caso de hacer refresh en la pagina con Angular?

Tags: angular

Cuando el usuario elige un producto, voy sumando el producto al carrito, es decir si elige 3 productos, en el carrito de la barra de navegacion aparece un total de 3 productos seleccionados. Todo esto me funciona, el problema esta que en el caso de que haga un refresh de la pagina (ya sea por accidente o por falta de conexion, etc..) el total de productos seleccionados en el carrito vuelve a 0.

aca el `service.cart`

```js
private bookArray: Book[] = [];
  private cart = new BehaviorSubject<Book[]>([]);
  cart$ = this.cart.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  addCart(book: Book){
    this.bookArray = [...this.bookArray, book];
    this.cart.next(this.bookArray);
  }
```

aca en mi `component.ts`, donde implemento el servicio en la funcion `addCarrito()`. Esta función se ejecuta cada vez que el usuario elige el producto para sumar al carrito de compras.

```js
addCarrito(book: Book){
    const idBookArray = [];
    let exist = false;
    // existe la sessionStorage ?
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('sessionShoppingCart') != null){
      // Obtiene la información almacenada desde sessionStorage
      const items = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionShoppingCart');
      // guardo el contenido de la session storage en array
      for (const value of items)
      {
        idBookArray.push(value);
      }
      // checkeo si el nuevo producto ya existe
      for (const item of idBookArray)
      {
        if (book.id_book.toString() === item)
        {
          exist = true;
        }
      }
      if (exist)
      {
        alert('El producto ya esta agregado en el carrito');
      }
      else{
        // guardo en array el nuevo proucto
        idBookArray.push(book.id_book);
        // grabo de nuevo el array en session storage
        sessionStorage.setItem('sessionShoppingCart', idBookArray.toString());
        // guardo el libro en el carrito
        this.cartService.addCart(book);
        alert('Producto agregado al carrito');
      }
    }
    else{
      // 1er carga del producto y creo la session storage
      idBookArray.push(book.id_book);
      // Almacena la información en sessionStorage
      sessionStorage.setItem('sessionShoppingCart', idBookArray.toString());
      // guardo el libro en el carrito
      this.cartService.addCart(book);
      alert('Producto agregado al carrito');
    }
  }
```

aca `main-nav.component.ts` donde obtengo el total de productos seleccionados en el carrito de compras

```js
export class MainNavComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  total = 0;

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private cartService: CartService
    ) {
        this.cartService.cart$.subscribe(libros => {
        this.total = libros.length;
       });
    }

}
```

aca `main-nav.component.html` mostrando el total de productos seleccionados.

```html
 <a class="btn-carrito" mat-raised-button color="warn" [matBadge]="total" matBadgeColor="warn">
        <mat-icon class="icon-shopping-cart">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
        Carrito
      </a>
```

Comment: Puedes guardar tus datos en el local storage o usando la api de indexedDB

Comment: Yo te recomiendo usar `localStorage` en vez de `sessionStorage`, el tema de que ya no tengas los registro de los elementos que agregaste a `sessionStorage` es por que la sesión ya se perdió simplemente (cerraste el navegador, abriste una nueva pestaña, etc.) por lo tanto si quisiera mantener el carrito lo mejor es usar `localStorage` así también cuando el usuario habrá otra pestaña tendrá el carrito como lo dejo, si cierra y abre el navegador, tendrá el mismo efecto, no se perderá el carrito.